# Pygame installation error: dependencies not found?

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pygame

When I type the command "pip3 install pygame" result in this:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9qmorw2a/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9qmorw2a/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-9qmorw2a/pygame/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9qmorw2a/pygame/
    Complete output (18 lines):
    
    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...
    
    
    Hunting dependencies...
    SDL     : found 1.2.15
    FONT    : not found
    IMAGE   : not found
    MIXER   : not found
    PNG     : found
    JPEG    : found
    SCRAP   : found
    PORTMIDI: found
    PORTTIME: found
    FREETYPE: found 21.0.15
    Missing dependencies
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: PyGame might have some version issue, what python version are you using? 3.8.2?

Comment: I am using python 3.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyGame is not compatible with python 3.8 versions so please try some older versions.

Use 3.6.8 it will support all the libraries available for python.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install python3-pygame
```